# How to scrape text from a hidden element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the text of the Swiss constitution from [Link](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/en) and convert it to markdown. However, the page source is different from what I see in the inspector: The source only contains no script warnings in various languages with the element `"app-root"` hidden.

The inspector shows a `.html` file served from [here](https://fedlex.data.admin.ch/filestore/fedlex.data.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/20210307/en/html/fedlex-data-admin-ch-eli-cc-1999-404-20210307-en-html-1.html) with which I am able to get the desired result. However, using this file directly would not allow me to scrape the subsequent revisions of the law automatically. Is there a way to extract the page source with the element "app-root" displayed?

This code returns "None" but works with the URL set to the .html file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from markdownify import markdownify

url = "https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/en"

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=opts)
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", {"id": "lawcontent"})

content = markdownify(str(div))

print(content[:200])
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're not giving any time for the driver to render the contents, resulting in incomplete source code.

[Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) can be used to wait for required elements to be visible/present etc. The given code below waits for the div content to be visible and then returns the page source code.

Code snippet-

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/en"

driver.get(url)
try:
    delay=20 #20 second delay
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lawcontent')))
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    div = soup.find("div", {"id": "lawcontent"})
    content = markdownify(str(div))
    print(content[:200])

#raises Exception if element is not visible within delay duration
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout!!!")
```

Comment: This has solved the issue; thank you for taking the time to answer. For anyone coming across this thread, the toolbar above the preface can be eliminated with: `soup.find('div', id="toolbar").decompose()`